# How to get value from children element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have html page with elements:

```
<div id="location-id" class="form-control">
      <span class="hub-trigger" data-hub-recordid="28">Germany</span>
</div>
```

I use `var element= document.getElementById('location-id')` to get html element.
Please tell me how can i get `28` from the `span` ?
I have tried to use var `id = element.getElementByTagName('data-hub-recordid')` with `val()`, `text()`, `innerText()` at the end but it didn't work as i expected.

Comment: The tag name is span!

Comment: @DevsiOdedra — jQuery doesn't make it any easier than standard DOM.

Comment: So many ways - getElements is PLURAL though: `document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].getAttribute("data-hub-recordid")` ... 
`document.getElementsByClassName('hub-trigger')[0].getAttribute("data-hub-recordid")` ... `document.querySelector("[data-hub-recordid]").getAttribute("data-hub-recordid")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
document.querySelector('.hub-trigger').getAttribute('data-hub-recordid')
```

or it

```
const parent = document.querySelector('#location-id');
const child = parent.querySelector('.hub-trigger');

const recordid = child.getAttribute('data-hub-recordid');
```